# How to make Horizontal line attach textview in recyclerview?

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

Am having a doubt regarding how to make the horizontal view to touch the textview while populating in  recyclerview , Now let me explain briefly i having a horizontal recyclerview in that adapter view holder i have horizontal view at the end of the textview which is center vertical to that textview, so when items are added each view must touch the textview like vertical dotted timeline but the view is not touching the textview as shown in the below image.[image]

Now let me post what i have tried so far

This is the layout that holding recyclerview:

```
<RelativeLayout android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/recyclerview"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Here am using that recyclerview in activity:

```
  Recyclerview recyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.recyclerview);
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this, LinearLayoutManager.HORIZONTAL, false));
        recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
        TrackingAdapter mAdapter = new TrackingAdapter(this.taskLogModelList,mTaskModel.getTaskID(),fm,String.valueOf(mLastLocation.getLatitude()),String.valueOf(mLastLocation.getLongitude()));
            recyclerView.setAdapter(mAdapter);
            mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

Here is the adapter am using :

```
public class TrackingAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<TrackingAdapter.ViewHolder> {
   private List<TaskLogModel> taskStatusFlowModels;
    private D2DKnocks appclass;
   private String Lat,Long;
    private FragmentManager fragmentManager;
    private String TaskID;
    DateFormat date,msimpleDateformat;
    public TrackingAdapter(List<TaskLogModel> taskStatusFlowModels,String TaskID,FragmentManager context,String Lat,String Long) {
        this.taskStatusFlowModels = taskStatusFlowModels;
        this.fragmentManager=context;
         date=new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
        msimpleDateformat = new SimpleDateFormat("hh.mm a");
        this.Lat=Lat;
        this.TaskID=TaskID;
        this.Long=Long;
         appclass=((D2DKnocks)D2DKnocks.getContext());
    }

    public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder  implements View.OnClickListener{
        private AvertaTextview txt_time;
        private Rubik txt_delivered;
     //   private AvertaButton btn_start;
        private RelativeLayout layout;
        private View view_right;

        public ViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            txt_time = itemView.findViewById(R.id.txt_time);
       //     btn_start=itemView.findViewById(R.id.start);
            layout=itemView.findViewById(R.id.layout);
            txt_delivered =  itemView.findViewById(R.id.txt_delivered);
            view_right = (View) itemView.findViewById(R.id.right_view_line);
            layout.setOnClickListener(this);
        }

        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            TaskLogModel taskLogModel=taskStatusFlowModels.get(getAdapterPosition());
            if(taskLogModel.getTaskStatusID()==0){
                TaskStatusDialog taskStatusDialog=new TaskStatusDialog();
                Bundle bundle=new Bundle();
                bundle.putInt("Size",taskStatusFlowModels.size());
                bundle.putString("Lat",Lat);
                bundle.putString("Long",Long);
                bundle.putString("TaskID",TaskID);
                taskStatusDialog.setArguments(bundle);
                taskStatusDialog.show(fragmentManager,"show");
            }

        }
    }

    @Override
    public TrackingAdapter.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View itemView = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.row_view_assignment_status, parent, false);
        return new ViewHolder(itemView);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(TrackingAdapter.ViewHolder holder, int position) {
             if (taskStatusFlowModels.get(position).getTaskStatusID() > 0) {
                StatusModel statusFlowModel = getStatusName(taskStatusFlowModels.get(position).getTaskStatusID());
                holder.txt_delivered.setText(statusFlowModel.getStatus());
                holder.txt_delivered.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.btn_arrived_bg);
                 try {
                     Date uppdateDate=date.parse(taskStatusFlowModels.get(position).getUpdateDateTime());
                     String updatedDate=msimpleDateformat.format(uppdateDate);
                     String[] each = updatedDate.split(" ");
                     String str = each[1].replace("AM", "am").replace("PM","pm");

//                     SpannableString ss1=  new SpannableString(each[0]);
//                     SpannableString ss2=new SpannableString(each[1]);
//                     ss1.setSpan(new AbsoluteSizeSpan(20), 0, each[0].length(), SPAN_INCLUSIVE_INCLUSIVE);
//                     ss2.setSpan(new AbsoluteSizeSpan(15), 0, each[1].length(), SPAN_INCLUSIVE_INCLUSIVE);
//                     CharSequence finalText = TextUtils.concat(ss1, " ", ss2);
                    holder.txt_time.setText(each[0]+" "+str);
                 } catch (ParseException e) {
                     e.printStackTrace();
                 }
                 GradientDrawable gradientDrawable = (GradientDrawable) holder.txt_delivered.getBackground();
                gradientDrawable.setColor(Color.parseColor(statusFlowModel.getStatusColor()));
            } else {

                    holder.txt_delivered.setText("Choose");
                    holder.txt_delivered.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.btn_choose_bg);
                    holder.txt_delivered.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#b1b1b1"));
            }
            if(taskStatusFlowModels.size()-1==position){
                holder.view_right.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            }
            else {
                holder.view_right.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            }
        }


    public StatusModel getStatusName(Integer statusID){
        for (int i=0;i<appclass.getStatusModelist().size();i++){
            if (appclass.getStatusModelist().get(i).getStatusID().equals(statusID)){
                return appclass.getStatusModelist().get(i);
            }

        }
        return null;
    }
    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {

        return taskStatusFlowModels.size();
    }
}
```

And below is the view holder layout:

```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
    android:orientation="vertical">


    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/layout">

        <com.trident.Hawkersky.service.CustomFonts.AvertaTextview
            android:id="@+id/txt_time"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
            android:drawableLeft="@drawable/ic_checked"
            android:drawablePadding="10dp"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="10.00 am"
            android:textColor="#444444"
            android:textSize="12sp"
           />

        <View
            android:id="@+id/vertical_line"
            android:layout_width="30dp"
            android:layout_height="20dp"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
             android:layout_below="@+id/txt_time"
           android:background="@drawable/vertical_dotted_line"
            android:layerType="software"
            android:visibility="visible" />
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/vertical_line"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
        <com.trident.Hawkersky.service.CustomFonts.Rubik
            android:id="@+id/txt_delivered"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="@dimen/thirty"
            android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
            android:singleLine="true"

            android:padding="@dimen/seven"
            android:background="@drawable/btn_delivered_bg"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="Delivered"
            android:textAllCaps="true"
            android:textColor="#FFF"
            android:textSize="13sp"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

        <View
            android:id="@+id/right_view_line" <--- this is the view
            android:layout_width="@dimen/hundred"
            android:layout_height="5dp"
            android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/txt_delivered"
            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
            android:layout_marginBottom="12dp"
            android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/txt_delivered"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/txt_delivered"
            android:background="@drawable/dotted"
            android:layerType="software"
            android:visibility="visible" />
</RelativeLayout>
    </RelativeLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Now what i need is i need that view to attach to the textview , but am getting like image above how to solve it.

Comment: Your question is unclear . Can you post the expected output ?

Comment: please check the image , i need that view to be connected in viewholder

Comment: Just organize your question, put the xml of the activity and the xml of the itemView. The picture is not explaining much..! is that a horizontal LinearLayout or what?

Comment: We will give it a try if you provide some clear details with code you tries and what you need to acheive.

Comment: please take a look at this guys

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try this and let know if you need further modifications.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                                             xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
                                             android:id="@+id/layout"
                                             android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                                             android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                             android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                                             android:orientation="vertical">


    <com.trident.Hawkersky.service.CustomFonts.AvertaTextview
        android:id="@+id/txt_time"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="5dp"
        android:drawableLeft="@drawable/ic_checked"
        android:drawablePadding="10dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="10.00 am"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="@+id/txt_delivered"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="@+id/txt_delivered"
        android:textColor="#444444"
        android:textSize="12sp"
        />

    <View
        android:id="@+id/vertical_line"
        android:layout_width="30dp"
        android:layout_height="20dp"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="@+id/txt_delivered"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="@+id/txt_delivered"
        android:layout_below="@+id/txt_time"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/txt_time"
        android:background="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
        android:layerType="software"
        android:visibility="visible"/>

    <com.trident.Hawkersky.service.CustomFonts.Rubik
        android:id="@+id/txt_delivered"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/thirty"
        android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
        android:background="@drawable/btn_delivered_bg"
        android:gravity="center"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/vertical_line"
        android:padding="@dimen/seven"
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:text="Delivered"
        android:textAllCaps="true"
        android:textColor="#FFF"
        android:textSize="13sp"
        android:textStyle="bold"/>

    <View
        android:id="@+id/right_view_line"
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="5dp"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/txt_delivered"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/txt_delivered"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toRightOf="@+id/txt_delivered"
        android:background="@drawable/dotted"
        android:layerType="software"
        android:visibility="visible"/>


</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Sorry, I had to use `ConstraintLayout`. If you haven't been using it before, please add this `implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'1` to your module level build.gradle.